# Where can I find an exhaustive list of web attack strings

Tags: xss, sql-injection, penetration-testing

I'm looking for exhaustive list(s) of web attack strings, which includes as many possible injection strings as possible, including SQLis , XSS, XPATH injections, SSIs, etc. Preferably encoded in various formats.
Anyone knows where to find these?

Comment: Interesting question! I guess the closes you can get, that I know of is the lists over ha.ckers.org: "http://ha.ckers.org/sqlinjection/" and "http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html". It would be nice to have a database with a collection of all these, though.

Comment: Yes, to use in conjunction with Burp intruder or WebSlayer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FuzzDB seems to be the answer 
http://code.google.com/p/fuzzdb/

Answer (score 0):

[Open Source Vulnerability Database](http://osvdb.org/)

Comment: I'm looking for a file with injection strings in each line, like: 
', ", <script> alert("hi");</script>, ../, etc

Comment: Also look at the links for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: in particular: Metasploit, w3af, and XSSer

Comment: Here's a good list: https://github.com/swisskyrepo/PayloadsAllTheThings/tree/master/XSS%20injection